# If on hover of this div, don't run script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a cursor which is active on hover of a pop up modal:

```
jQuery(".modal").on("mousemove", function(){
    jQuery(".cursor").css("transform", "translate(" + (event.clientX - 25) + "px, " + (event.clientY - 25) + "px)");
})
```

However, within this modal, I have icons which are clickable (i.e. socials). Since this `.cursor` is active all across the `.modal`, those icons won't be clickable.

What I'm trying to do (in pseudo):

```
if( jQuery(window).width() <= 1024 ){
    if (/* not hovering over class .icon */) {
        // then show cursor 
        jQuery(".modal").on("mousemove", function(){
            jQuery(".cursor").css("transform", "translate(" + (event.clientX - 25) + "px, " + (event.clientY - 25) + "px)");
        })
    } 
}
```

How do I approach this? and is this the correct way of going about things?

Comment: hello, can you include enough HTML and CSS to demonstrate what `.modal` and `.cursor` actually do?

Comment: I suggest you apply mouseenter event handler to each icon which can set a flag, and a mouseleave handler which clears it. Then in your mousemove handler for the modal, check the value of the flag and only change the cursor if it's false

Comment: Tried to create a snippet/jsfiddle, but your discription of "icons which are clickable" doesn't really make sense.  Assuming these are inside the "cursor", you'll never be able to point at them to stop them moving.  https://jsfiddle.net/w2mg6f14/ If you need more help, you'll need to create a working snippet show the "cursor" and how the "socials" relate in the HTML hierarchy.

Comment: It could be that you move the "socials" outside of the "cursor" and place them using absolute positioning to the "modal".